# Installing a software from command line windows- with parameters

Tags: .net, windows, command-line, package, asp.net-core

I have this command

```
DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1
```

but where and how to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a [commandline (cmd.exe) in the folder where the Exe is stored](http://code.kliu.org/cmdopen/), paste the command there and press ENTER to run it.

Comment: Thanks the installation has started